# Error while connecting to sql through windows authentication

Tags: c#, connection-string

I am using the following code to connect to sql throgh windows authentication.

```
string connctionstring = "connectionString={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=SSPI;";
string _connctionstring = string.Format(connctionstring, datasource, initialCatalogue);
SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(_connctionstring);
_connection.Open();
```

But i am getting the following error. Help please.I am able to login through sql server.

[image]

Comment: what's "connectionString"?

Comment: it should be Data Source = {0}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connection string [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709346(v=vs.85).aspx) is not correct
Change to this:

```
string connctionstring = "Data Source={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

Or

```
string connctionstring = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

Answer (score 2):

While [Peyman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30474806/80274) does cover the basic issue (`connectionString` is not a valid key for the string) a better solution is to use a [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this will also help you do proper escaping if you have odd characters in your string (for example if your database name contained a space)

```
var scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
scsb.DataSource = datasource;
scsb.InitialCatalog = initialCatalogue;
scsb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

//You also really should wrap your connections in using statements too.
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(scsb.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    //...
}
```